# CodeIgniter: AJAX returns html content of current page

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

All AJAX calls (I use jQuery) on page */index.php/contracts/add/new* return full html of this page. But these calls on */index.php/contracts/* work fine. It seems like error is not in the PHP or JS code, but in the configuration.

Here is my controller **Contracts** with two functions that I use for AJAX (`get_info()` and `add_contract()`):

```
<?php
    class Contracts extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('contracts_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('templates/menu');
            $this->load->view('contracts/index');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
            $this->load->view('contracts/scripts');
    }

    public function add($smth)
    {                
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('templates/menu');
        $this->load->view('contracts/add');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        $this->load->view('contracts/scripts_add');
    }

    public function get_info($contract_id)
    {
        $data = $this->contracts_model->get_contract($contract_id);     

        echo $data;
    }

    public function add_contract($contract_id)
    {
        echo "ok";          
    }

   }
 ?>
```

AJAX calls in my views:

```
var contract_id = 1;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contracts/get_info/"+contract_id, 
            cache: false, 
            async: false,  
            success: function(data){                                        
                console.log(data);

            }
        });

contract_id = 2; 
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "contracts/add_contract/" + contract_id, 
        cache: false, 
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
             console.log(data); 
            }
        });
```

So I successfully get `$data` from `get_info()` and "ok" from `add_contract()` in index page, but in *contracts/add* these calls return all html content of page *contracts/add*.

---

UPD: 
Problem solved in comments. 
In AJAX calls in    `contracts/add` page URL must be changed from `contracts/get_info` to `/index.php/contracts/get_info`.

Comment: It is because you are loading the views in the add function. AJAX will return whatever is the output on the page,apparently it is the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contracts/add` return the full HTML because you're specifically loading it. Try removing 'wrapping' views:

```
public function add($smth) { //what's $smth all about - you're not using it
    $this->load->view('contracts/add');
}
```

Edit: You could also do something like this if you need to show full HTML for non-ajax requests (though it would be preferable to use a separate controlles for ajax vs. non-ajax).

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        $this->load->view('contracts/add');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('templates/menu');
        $this->load->view('contracts/add');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        $this->load->view('contracts/scripts_add');
    }
}
```

Comment: Function      add() just loading my "add page", and the view      'contracts/add' contains only HTML input form. So I need all those views, yes. Creating separate controllers didn't help, the problem remains:     index() function for *start page* and     add() function for *add page* are equal, but AJAX calls from *start page* work fine, although all calls from *add page* (to this controller or to another site) returns html of *add page*.

Comment: Try putting a leading slash `/` in front of the url in your ajax call. Does this fix your problem?

Comment: Yes, I added a leading slash and changed the URL and it started to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the `add()` function, you are loading all the `Views`, thats why you are recieving all the `HTML` content and you are passing this variable **$smth** in the `add()` function but you are not using it anywhere.

```
 public function add($smth)
    {           
    // YOU ARE LOADING ALL THE VIEWS A.K.A ALL HTML CONTENT     
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('templates/menu');
        $this->load->view('contracts/add');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        $this->load->view('contracts/scripts_add');
    }
```

You can load those views in some other function and return the ONLY `datas` that you want to return from the `add()` function.

Comment: Still don't get it. The 'index()' function for start page is the same and all work fine there. Please, can you write a sample, because I don't understand how it might look like?

Comment: What exactly you want to do in that `add` function?

Comment: Load a HTML page with header, menu, footer and input form.

Comment: Well thats what it is doing now, and hence you are getting all the HTML content where as in `get_info` function you are just returning `$data` and thus you just get whatever is in that `$data`, so whats the issue now?

Comment: *add()* and *index()* are just functions that load pages from which I do the AJAX calls. The issue is that in **index** page *get_info* function returns *$data*, but in **add** page the same call returns full content of **add** page.

Answer (score 0):

Put exit after echo data.

```
public function get_info($contract_id)
{
    $data = $this->contracts_model->get_contract($contract_id);     

    echo $data;
    exit;
}
```